# How to count repeated label between given RFMin and RFMax

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading the following CSV file that have three columns and multiple rows:

```
Notation    RFMin       RFMax 
 AA100     1000         3333  
 BB200      3300        4500
```

Currently my output file looks like this:

```
 Notation   RFRange          Label 
 AA100       1000            AG, IF
 AA100       1259            AG, IF
 AA100       1518            AG, TE, WW 
 AA100       1777            AG, TE, WW
 AA100       2037            Unknown
 AA100       2296            Unknown
 AA100       2555            MH, WE   
 AA100       2814            MH, WE
 AA100       3074            DT, MH, WE
 AA100       3333            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       3300            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       3433            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       3567            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       3700            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       3833            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       3967            DT, MH, WE
 BB200       4100            Unknown
 BB200       4233            Unknown
 BB200       4366            Unknown
 BB200       4500            Unknown
```

1. I am printing 10 numbers between `RFMIn` and `RFMax` with using a linspace
2. I am printing Notations Based on the `N` numbers of samples between `RFMin` and `RFMax`,
3. I am labeling on those 10 numbers from #1 based on the condition exists

How should I do #4?

4. I want to find out how many times each labels are repeating in between each `RFmin` and `RFMax`. For example,  between `1000-3333` total of `'AG'` repeat 4 times, `'MH'` repeats 5 times, `'IF'` repeats 2 times, `'WW'` 2 times, and so on... ,  in `3300-4500` - `'AG'` repeats 0 times, `'MH'` repeats 6 times,  `'IF'` repeats 0 times, and so on…

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = csv.read_csv(filePath)
N = 10
RFarray = []
Notation=[]
c = np.zeros((df.shape[0], N))

for index, col in df.iterrows():
    RFMin = col['RFMin']
    RFMax = col['RFMax']
    c[col] = np.linspace(RFMin, RFMax, N)

for ir, r1 in enumerate(c):
   for b in r1:
       RFarray.append(b)    
       Notation.append(df.loc[ir, 'Notation'])

dict = {'Notation': Notation,'RFRange': RFarray}

data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
data['Label'] = 'Unknown'
data.loc[(data['RFRange'] < 1300), 'Label'] = 'AG, IF'
data.loc[(data['RFRange'] >=1300) & (data['RFRange'] <=2000), 'Label'] = 'AG, TE, WW'
data.loc[(data['RFRange'] >=2500) & (data['RFRange'] <=2900), 'Label'] = 'MH, WE'
data.loc[(data['RFRange'] >=3000) & (data['RFRange'] <=4000), 'Label'] = 'DT, MH, WE'
data.to_csv('Output.csv', header=True, index=None, float_format=%.2f )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, merge the 2 dataframes, convert label to list, add the range filter, groupby notation and concatenate all the Labels together into 1 list per notation and then use the `Counter` from `collections` to count each element in the list:

```
from collections import Counter

df2['Label'] = df2['Label'].str.split(',')
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Notation'])
df = df[(df['RFRange']>df['RFMin']) & (df['RFRange']<df['RFMax'])]
df = df.groupby(by='Notation', as_index=False).agg({'Label': 'sum'})
df['counts'] = df['Label'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))
print(df)

  Notation                                              Label                                             counts
0    AA100  [AG, IF, AG, TE, WW, AG, TE, WW, Unknown, Unkn...  {'AG': 3, 'IF': 1, 'TE': 2, 'WW': 2, 'Unknown'...
1    BB200  [DT, MH, WE, DT, MH, WE, DT, MH, WE, DT, MH, W...          {'DT': 5, 'MH': 5, 'WE': 5, 'Unknown': 3}
```

Comment: I have couple of rows with same name of Notation. is there any away to represent Based on RFMin and RFMax. Like 1000-3333 [AG, IF, AG, TE, .........] 3300-4500 [DT, MH, WE, DT, MH, ......]